# Amazon SES HTTPS Query API Authentication error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hmac, amazon-ses

I have been trying to send an email using Amazon SES Https Query API.
but the Signature that I calculate and send to aws is not accepted.

I get this error message.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing     method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>c97bd130-24c9-11e6-924a-b59d7ac9182b</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

here is my java Code

```
public class SendSESMail {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, SignatureException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    String dateString = format.format(new Date());

    final String ENDPOINT = "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
    final String AWS_ACCESS = "ACCESS_KEY";
    final String AWS_SECRET = "SECRET_KEY";

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(ENDPOINT);

    String authString = generateAuthHeader(AWS_ACCESS, AWS_SECRET, dateString);

    List<NameValuePair> formVals = new ArrayList<>();
    formVals.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Action", "SendRawEmail"));
    formVals.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Destination.ToAddresses.member.1", "bhanuka.yd@gmail.com"));
    formVals.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message.Body.Text.Data", "I hope you see the body."));
    formVals.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Message.Subject.Data", "This is a Unique Subject"));
    formVals.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Source", "test@test.com"));

    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formVals);

    post.setHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.toString());
    post.setHeader("Date", dateString);
    post.setHeader("X-Amzn-Authorization", authString);

    post.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    response.getEntity().writeTo(System.out);

 }

 public static String generateAuthHeader(String accessKey, String secret, String dateString) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException {
    String authHeaderVal = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=" + accessKey + ",Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature=";
    authHeaderVal += generateSignature(dateString, secret);
    return authHeaderVal;
 }

 public static String generateSignature(String message, String secret) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secretKey);
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
 }
}
```

the first time I tried it out , it gave me this error

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
 <Error>
   <Type>Sender</Type>
   <Code>ValidationError</Code>
   <Message>1 validation error detected: Value null at 'rawMessage' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null</Message>
 </Error>
 <RequestId>9a986157-24ca-11e6-9864-3fdeb433e3c8</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

it was because the signature had an "=" sign at the end , so I used

```
encodeBase64URLSafeString();
```

method to convert the signature to Base64 instead of

```
encodeBase64String();
```

So what I am doing wrong here,
Please someone help me out here 
Thanks.

Comment: I think the string you are signing is not correct. Although not the same service here is an example Java code snippet for signing an aws HTTP request with signature version 2.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AuthJavaSampleSig2.html

Comment: but here 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-authentication.html
it says 
"To create the string to sign, calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC hash with the Date header value, your secret access key as the key, and SHA256 or SHA1 as the hash algorithm"

Comment: thats exactly what I did. except for when converting to Base64 I used URLSafe version, instead normal. because normal one has an "=" sign which causes an another error

Comment: You are only generating the hmac on datestring

Comment: The string to sign format is incorrect.

Comment: can you please explain ? I really want to get this rite :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113218/discussion-between-bhanuka-yd-and-shibashis).

Comment: I am on my ph so can't help with code ritenow. Compare toSign variable in the example is different in example I shared

Comment: You are not adding request method, request uri canonical QS to the input string for signinh

Comment: @Shibashis this is Signature **Version 3**.  Not 2 or 4, it's completely different than both.

Comment: so in "X-Amzn-Authorization" header , "AWS3-HTTP" means verison3 ?
the SES developer guide says to do it exactly the same (hash the Date in GMT format and convert it to base64). I think the problem is using that URLSafe Base64 instead of normal Base64 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that I can use the Signature V4 to authenticate my HTTP request.

anyone having this problem, can follow the exact process in the below [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and you will be able to authenticate.

One thing to keep in mind is that, the request time should be in ISO8601 format, in UTC

here is a method to calculate the current time in UTC timezone.

```
public static String getUTCTimeISO8601Format() {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    SimpleDateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");//ISO8601 B8601DZw.d format
    iso8601Format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    return iso8601Format.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```